# I am developing duolingo type sentence practice in javascript. I have implemented it but it needs more improvement

Tags: javascript, html

I have used following code to develop sentence grammar practice. When I click button then order should to maintained. I want it when button clicked then it should hide but after click on top button again show up.
Move sentence to left if there is blank. Also show button again if words clicked again.
Should using only buttons for showing at top also at bottom?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title> 
</head>

<body>

<div id="sen">I am learning JavaScript by developing a simple project.</div>
<br>
<div id="dash"></div>
<br>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="val"></div>

<script>
var sen = document.getElementById("sen").innerHTML;
var senTrim = sen.trim();
var senArr = senTrim.split(/\s+/);

var dashElement = "";
for(i=0;i<senArr.length;i++)
{
//alert(senArr[i]);
    dashElement += "<div onclick='funDiv(this.id);' style='display: inline'" + "id = dashid" + i + ">"    + '__ '  + '</div>';

}

var dash = document.getElementById("dash");
dash.innerHTML = dashElement;

//var dashID = document.getElementById("dashid0").innerHTML;
//var dash1 = document.getElementById("val");
//dash1.innerHTML= dashID;

var htmlElements = "";
for (var i = 0; i < senArr.length; i++) {
   htmlElements += "<button onclick='fun(this.id);' id = 'btn" + i + "'>" + senArr[i] + '</button>';
}
var container = document.getElementById("container");
container.innerHTML = htmlElements;

var ii = 0;
function funDiv(clicked){
//alert(clicked);
var inText = document.getElementById(clicked).innerHTML;
document.getElementById(clicked).innerHTML = " __ " ; 
ii--;
}

function fun(clicked){
//alert(clicked);
document.getElementById(clicked).style.display = "none";  
document.getElementById("dashid" + ii).innerHTML = document.getElementById(clicked).innerHTML + " ";
//document.getElementById(clicked).remove(); 
ii++;
}

</script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Image taken from :- https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/34275146/sentence-discussion-from-Together-skill-lesson-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented it using appendChild and remove functions of JavaScript.

```html
<html>

<body>

  <div id="sen">I am learning JavaScript by developing a simple project.</div>
  <br>
  <div id="dash"></div>
  <br>
  <div id="container"></div>
  
  <script>
    var sen = document.getElementById("sen").innerHTML;
    var senTrim = sen.trim();
    var senArr = senTrim.split(/\s+/);
    var dashElement = "";

    var btnElements = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < senArr.length; i++) {
      btnElements += "<button onclick='btnClick(this.id);' id = 'btn" + i + "'> " + senArr[i] + ' </button>';
    }

    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    container.innerHTML = btnElements;
    var picked = 0;
    function dashClick(clicked) {
        //console.log(clicked);
        var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
        var dash = document.getElementById("dash");
        dashChild = dash.childNodes;
        console.log(document.getElementById(clicked).innerText);
        for(i=0;i<senArr.length;i++){
            if(document.getElementById(clicked).innerText.trim() == buttons[i].innerText.trim()){
                //console.log("Match");
                buttons[i].style.opacity = "1";
                buttons[i].style.pointerEvents = "auto";
            }
        }
        document.getElementById(clicked).remove(); // remove clicked text 
    }

    // Button click
    function btnClick(clicked) {    
        var dashElement = document.createElement("div"); 
        var text = document.getElementById(clicked).innerText;
        dashElement.style.display = "inline";
        dashElement.innerHTML = "<div style='display: inline' onclick='dashClick(this.id);' id=" + picked +"> " + text + " </div>"; // add text at top of button
        document.getElementById("dash").appendChild(dashElement);
        picked++;
        document.getElementById(clicked).style.opacity = "0"; //hide button that has been clicked
        document.getElementById(clicked).style.pointerEvents = "none";
    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```html
<html>

<body>

  <div id="sen">I am learning JavaScript by developing a simple project.</div>
  <br>
  <div id="dash"></div>
  <br>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <div id="val"></div>

  <script>
    var sen = document.getElementById("sen").innerHTML;
    var senTrim = sen.trim();
    var senArr = senTrim.split(/\s+/);
    var dashElement = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < senArr.length; i++) {
      dashElement += `<div onclick='dashClick(this.id);' style='display: inline' id=dash${i}> __ </div>`;
    }

    var dash = document.getElementById("dash");
    dash.innerHTML = dashElement;
    var htmlElements = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < senArr.length; i++) {
      htmlElements += "<button onclick='btnClick(this.id);' id = 'btn" + i + "'>" + senArr[i] + '</button>';
    }

    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    container.innerHTML = htmlElements;
    var picked = 0;

    function dashClick(clicked) {
      const dash = document.getElementById(clicked);
      dash.innerHTML = " __ ";
      const btn = document.getElementById(`btn${dash.btnId}`);
      btn.style.display = "inline";
      picked--;
    }

    function btnClick(clicked) {
      var btnId = clicked.replace('btn', '');
      document.getElementById(clicked).style.display = "none";
      const dash = document.getElementById("dash" + picked)
      dash.innerHTML = document.getElementById(clicked).innerHTML + " ";
      dash.btnId = btnId;
      picked++;
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```